# timepicker: how to change the time with the keyboard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, timepicker

i am using boostrap timepicker : https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-timepicker#form-timepicker

I entered this code:

```
            <b-form-timepicker
              v-model="timeSlot.timeStart"
              minutes-step="15"
              @input="getCurrentTime(timeSlot)"
            ></b-form-timepicker>
```

I can't find a method that can make me change the time via the pc keyboard

Comment: do you want to type the time without using that arrow up/down?

Comment: that's right, I would like to write the time with the numbers on the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says the following:

> always returns a string in the format of 'HH:mm:ss' which is the same format returned by native browser  controls. The value will be in the range of '00:00:00' up to '23:59:59' (24-hour clock using the 'h23' hour cycle syntax). If no time is selected, then  returns an empty string ('').

https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-timepicker#form-timepicker

So you need to implement something which only edits the value in `timeslot.timeStart` by keyboard. For an easy example you could add another simple `input`-field and also give it `timeslot.timeStart` as v-model.

```html
<input type="text" v-model="timeslot.timeStart" />
```

You should see your `b-form-timepicker` change if you change the value in the `input`-field and other way round. After you have understood this, it should be easy to implement some base event-handlers, which changes your `timeSlot.timeStart` while having your `b-form-timepicker` in focus, based on your keyboard input.

You can find an example for that in the documentation:
https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-timepicker#button-only-mode

Answer (score 0):

You could use `button-only` mode and add an input where you type time :

```
    <b-input-group class="mb-3">
      <b-form-input
        id="example-input"
        v-model="timeSlot.timeStart"
        type="text"
        placeholder="HH:mm:ss"
      ></b-form-input>
      <b-input-group-append>
        <b-form-timepicker
          v-model="timeSlot.timeStart"
          button-only
          right
          show-seconds
          locale="en"
          aria-controls="example-input"
        ></b-form-timepicker>
      </b-input-group-append">
    </b-input-group>
```